# How can I sending json data using Spring RestTemplate to PHP server

Tags: php, spring, resttemplate

I am developing an android application and i using spring RestTemplate to get data from and post data to a PHP server. I tried to post data to PHP server, but PHP server got nothing. How can I post json data using Spring RestTemplate to PHP server and get the json from PHP server?

Comment: using php? Is there a php flavor of spring? Never heard of such thing before.

Comment: I had make a mistake for my poor english. I had correct it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by myself. I add FormHttpMessageConverter to RestTemplate like this:

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());

And then I can post json data to PHP server. I got the json data in PHP server using:

$jsonData = $_POST['json'];

Answer (score 0):

I fixed with

```
MultiValueMap<String, ArrayList<persona>> parts = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();

parts.add("json", aaper);    

restTemplate.postForLocation(url,parts);
```